# RandomName generator in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generator

I am having a small annoying issue. I am trying to make a random Name generator in Unity, which must be displayed in a text box.
The problem is that it is not displaying anything in the textBox, even though I've followed few examples, tried different options but it didn't work.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class GeneratorG : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject TextBox;
    public int TheNumber;
    public string TheGenre;
private void PickRandomFromList()
    {
        string[] genres = new string[] { "Rock", "Classic", "Jazz" };
        string randomName = genres[Random.Range(0, genres.Length)];
        TextBox.GetComponent<Text>().text = "" + randomName;
    }
}
```

I will put more names after that, but I am trying to make it work at first. Do you know where the problem can be? Or do you have another solution for this tiny task?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do you call `PickRandomFromList`?

Comment: You need to attach the textbox object in your scene to TextBox field in inspector.

Comment: PickRandomFromList is just the name of the function.
I connected it with the text Box and I have connected the text box with the button in OnClick(0 but it does not find the function.

Comment: @ddcastrodd `UnityEngine` defines a [`Random`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.html) class which includes a [`Range`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) static method with a couple overloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what causes this exactly from this code snippet only but here somethings that you should check.
1- Check if you referenced the TextBox that you want to show the random name in through the unity editor.
2- Check if you referenced this function on the generate button through the unity editor to call it when it's clicked.

Comment: hehe, After the last changes I also forgot to repair the reference xD . Thank you!

Comment: It happens more often than you would think. I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to change the text of the GameObject TextBox you can put it on top as

```
public Text TextBox;
```

After that you should be able to change it with:

```
string randomName = genres[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, genres.Length)];
TextBox.text = " " + randomName;
```

Also make sure that you have set the TextBox in the inspector field, where your script is currently located.

Comment: This will never select "Jazz" - it should be `UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, genres.Length)`

Comment: Oh I copied it from one of my other projects, that's why I assumed it was correct. But it seems like I need to fix something, thanks for the help XD

Comment: Yeah, it didn't selected it, but it worked. Thanks to both of you! :) :P